# Python string format unsigned decimal

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've just started learning python (using 2.7) and I'm confused about what the string format "%u" does.

It's described as "unsigned decimal" but then I get this behaviour:

```
>>> print "%u" % -100
-100
>>> x = -100
>>> print "%u" % x
-100
```

Isn't it supposed to print -100 as an unsigned decimal? What does "%u" actually do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Python 2.7 documentation `%u` is actually an obsolete type and is evaluated the same as `%d`. Read more here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting.

[image: str conversion type]

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I managed to overlook the official documentation.